# Unable to instanciate TextToSpeech only on speak() request

Tags: android, optimization, text-to-speech

I'm trying to implement TextToSpeech in a service that could be running for long times, so I'd like to instantiate TTS only if very necessary, for memory/battery saving reasons.

Is there a way to implement this handling multiple speak() requests?

In example, the application needs to use TTS: TTS is instantiated and initialised, once ready then speak is processed and finally shutdown(). But if TTS is already speaking (or instantiated) and the application needs another text synthesis, I would like that this call could be handled through the still alive TTS instance rather than a new one (in order to obtain flush ability).

Is there a clean and functional way to implement this?

Thank you very much in advance.

ADDENDUM: Do you think that this solution of creating and destroying will really help with battery saving or should I leave TTS in memory and let Android system manage everything?

Comment: Just make your TTS object null when you shut it down and check for null when you want to use it. If it is null then instantiate the object again.

Comment: This is my current implementation, but it is buggy, sometimes the first notification after the TexToSpeech initialisation is not triggered and other times it is killed before speak() finished its job. Here is the whole class https://gist.github.com/turlando/5e3de7c4ba70984baa69

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this using a Singleton/Queue Combination.

If a Text-To-Speak Command is issued you Enqueue the request (Simply using a ConcurrentQueue in Java and some custom Request Object from a self designed class) Then if the second Thread is not running it is started, otherwise it is notified.

The second Thread instanciates TTS, polls the first item in the Queue, and processes it. Then it will check the Queue again, if the Queue is empty it will shutdown TTS and exit, else it will process the next element in the Queue.

You can optionally add a timeout, so the Thread will wait for X Seconds after the last TTS Request, before shutting down.

Comment: Thank you very much. ConcurrentQueue is something I never used before. Beyond the Javadoc, is there some lecture you would suggest me?

Comment: JavaDocs are pretty good in this area - otherwise you should read some general tutorials about synchronization between threads (in essence putting synchronize(queue) around starting and stopping the thread...

Comment: I've made those edits to my code. I don't know if I've actually implemented the BlockingQueue correctly, but I am still missing some speak(), maybe more now than before. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/turlando/d3494870443c28bc7f5e

Comment: Just had a quick look at your code... You shouldn't start a new Thread every time, only if the old one is not running anymore! And you should use a single Queue as a singleton shared between the Thread and the Method which is invoked by Android...

Comment: I'm so sorry for me being such a noob with Java, could you give me some more informations about singletons?

When I call Synthesizer.synthesize(), it will create a new thread for TTSQueue.AppendNotification(), which will enqueue my String, right? Once it is enqueued, it starts a new thread for TTSQueue.RunTTS; is this method called until the queue is empty?

Addictionally, I think that the while (ttsStatus) is not working properly; is it a wrong way to check if TTS is initialised and ready to speak()?

Thank you for the time you're wasting with me.